# Request permission to read URI

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am attempting to use the gif feature in the soft keyboard on android. I can follow the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard#adding_image_support_to_imes) and get the URI for the gif as well as load it into and imageView using Glide.

However if I want to send that URI to a 2nd device and display it inside an imageView on the 2nd device I can't find out how to request the URI read permission.

Glide gives the error

Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.libraries.inputmethod.fileprovider.CrashResistantFileProvider.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: Hey I Have same use case like you. how can i get file from that uri ? i want to save to local storage for other ref.  Can You help me regard this

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file keep in mind that the authorities attribute of File `Provider` is unique

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.contentprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        tools:replace="android:authorities">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

create a file provider_paths in the xml folder under res. If there is no such directory of xml create that and create the file and paste the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <paths>
         <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
     </paths>
```

After doing this then where you need a uri you can call like this to get the file uri

```
final Uri data = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.example.contentprovider", new File(path));
```